# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007::securityScan()

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library, while uploading a xlsx file getting the below error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007::securityScan() in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/qms/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php
>   on line 80

My upload php code;

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
   if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
           && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
   } else {
       echo "Invalid file!";
       exit();
   }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file!";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?